# Why is joining a CTE so slow?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, common-table-expression, with-statement

I have a query looking like this

```sql
WITH 
events AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Table1 ae
    WHERE '2022-04-21 06:25:22' >= ae.Stamp
    AND ae.Stamp > '2022-04-21 05:25:22'
),
users AS 
(
    SELECT User,COUNT(*) AS cnt 
    FROM events 
    GROUP BY User
    HAVING cnt > 60
)
SELECT *
FROM events e join users u on e.User = u.User
```

that executes extremely slow. Executing the two CTEs takes roughly 13s and events contains 3009 records, users contains 2 records. However running the query as shown takes more than 30 minutes :-O

If I change the last line to explicitly comparing the users from users table

```
FROM events e join users u on e.User in ('User1','User2')
```

the query executes in 22 seconds!

Why is the join so slow ?
Is there a better way to implement the query ?

Thanks

---update---

Based on the input from SOS I changed the query to

```
WITH 
events AS (
    SELECT *,
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY User) AS TotalUser 
    FROM Table1 ae
    WHERE '2022-04-21 06:25:22' >= ae.Stamp
    AND ae.Stamp > '2022-04-21 05:25:22'
)
SELECT *
FROM events e 
WHERE TotalUser > 60
```

now with an execution time of 6s (on same data)  :-).

Comment: Run an `explain`.  Also, is there a typo in the date comparison? I'd expect to see  `>=` and `<` rather than `>=` and `>`.  As far as alternatives, you could try window functions: `COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY User)` instead of cte's  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b3cc12efe12c7f35f2ce5e252c8a6de4

Comment: Prefixed EXPLAIN but I didn't get any clues from that. However using your over partition worked for me. I still need the WITH as I need to filter on the value. Now the execution time is 6s :-)

I still need to understand why the performance was so poor on the other construct...

Comment: You are right on the datetime-intervals - mine is closed in the top which is not typical.

Comment: *still need the WITH...* The derived query used in the fiddle does the same thing, i.e. allows you to filter on the calculated count (though my filter logic may be slightly off, but you can change that). However, if the performance is good for both, either one is okay.  I'm not sure why it's so slow either. Could you post the EXPLAIN anyway? Maybe someone will spot a clue from it.

Comment: Any change if you move the `HAVING cnt > 60` clause to the outer query: i.e. `SELECT ... FROM events e join users u on e.User = u.User WHERE cnt > 60`?

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: I appologize  - I didn't know fiddle - I thought it was just an URL for you so I didn't see it before now. I created the same without the nested SELECT and without that you are not allowed to filter on the partiioned field no matter if the query is in the field list as a named or directly specified in the where clause.

Comment: Gotcha.  If you want help figuring out why the cte was slow, do post the information O. Jones mentioned, and I'm sure someone will have some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating this index.

```sql
CREATE INDEX ts_user ON Table1 (Stamp, User)
```

It should help both the date-range filter and the GROUP BY.

And, if you use SSMS -- Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio -- this tip is for you: Right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works better:

```
SELECT u.*, ae.cnt
  FROM (
    SELECT User, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM Table1
        WHERE Stamp >  '2022-04-21 05:25:22'
          AND Stamp <= '2022-04-21 05:25:22' + INTERVAL 1 HOUR 
        GROUP BY User
        HAVING cnt > 60
     ) AS ae
  JOIN Users AS u  USING(User)
```

Possible indexes:

```
Table1:  INDEX(Stamp, User)
Users:   PRIMARY KEY(User) or INDEX(User), but not both
```